# Don't understand simple logarithm problem with fractional base

Tags: logarithms

$$3\log_{\frac{4}{9}}\sqrt[4]{\frac{27}{8}}$$

$$\log_{\frac{3}{2}}\frac{16}{81}$$

I understand using the expansion property to expand the division into a subtraction but how do I proceed from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First observe that
$$
3\log_\frac{4}{9}\sqrt[4]{\frac{27}{8}} =\frac{3}{4}\log_\frac{4}{9}\frac{27}{8}
$$
So all we need now is to compute the log term. By definition $\log_ab=y$ means that $a^y=b$ so we need to find $y$ such that
$$
\left(\frac{4}{9}\right)^y=\frac{27}{8}
$$
Expanding this, we have
$$
\left(\frac{2^2}{3^2}\right)^y=\frac{3^3}{2^3}
$$
or
$$
\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2y}=\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^3
$$
and we're almost there, if we could make the left and right sides have the same base. Can you carry on from there?

Comment: Gotcha. 3/2 ^ -3 = 27/8, so 2y = -3, y = -3/2. The final answer would be (3/4) * (-3/2) = -9/8.

Edit: it's correct.

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to not go to the subtraction step. Observe, for example, for the second expression that $\frac{16}{81} = (\frac{2}{3})^4 =  (\frac{3}{2})^{-4}$, and hence the second logarithm is equal to $-4$. The first one is similar. Let me know if you have any difficulties.